# JRE (sun 1.6 21) crash with SIGBUS on Linux Debian 5

Tags: linux, tfs, debian, java

I have problems with JRE on Linux Debian 5.
JRE (sun 1.6 21) crash with SIGBUS on Debian 5 (kernel 2.6.26) during TEE-CLC java application execute.

TEE-CLC-10.1.0 is a java client application for Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS).

Here is the java virtul mashine command line:

> exec java -Xmx512M -classpath
>   "$CLC_CLASSPATH" "-Dcom.microsoft.tfs.jni.native.base-directory=$BASE_DIRECTORY/native"
>     $RANDOM_DEVICE_PROPERTY com.microsoft.tfs.client.clc.vc.Main "$@"

When I try to execute the command (get files from server): **tf get -r -force {branch_name}** it start getting files and then minute or two later craches with the following error message:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0xb77d3422, pid=29386, tid=3076802752
>
> JRE version: 6.0_21-b06
>   Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (17.0-b16 mixed mode linux-x86 )
>   Problematic frame:
>   C  [+0x422]  __kernel_vsyscall+0xe
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
>   /...../..../...../hs_err_pid29386.log
>   Segmentation fault.

I have about 900M free memory. I have checked limits: ulimit -a .
I have three other Linux Debian 5 computers and they works fine with the same settings.
I have checked everything . I don' t know why JRE don't work properly.

Does anybody have any idea how to handle it? What is wrong with JRE or with my Debian 5?

Comment: Did you look at the log file `/root/TDCode/branches/hs_err_pid29386.log`? It might contain a stack trace which could give you a hint in what native library it is crashing.

Comment: I have checked this log file but could not extract useful information.
Stack: [0xbf9f6000,0xbfa46000],  sp=0xbfa416b4,  free space=12dbfa41030k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [+0x422]  __kernel_vsyscall+0xe
C  [java+0x5d78]
C  [java+0x17f6]
C  [libc.so.6+0x16455]  __libc_start_main+0xe5
Does it mean that i have error in libc? But it is standart library, other programs work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it is rare to get a faulty program to fail with a `SIGBUS`: error checking by compilers makes it hard to generate an odd memory address. The few times I've seen them recently was (IIRC) because I was using an incompatible shared library or `.o` file.

Is the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable set for the executing program? If so, it might be causing the program to use an incorrect shared library.